# "Package does not match intended download" error when running yum update

Tags: linux, centos, repository, redhat, yum

I've run a yum update and get the below error:

```
Downloading packages:
scx-1.6.4-7.universal.x64.rpm  FAILED
https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/scx-1.6.4-7.universal.x64.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=packages-microsoft-com-prod clean metadata
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  scx-1.6.4-7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I tried running the suggested command but it made no difference when I ran yum update again afterwards.

Comment: This happened to me when the /var disk partition filled up. I manually deleted the yum cache and it started working again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just encountered the same issue. Looks like Microsoft goofed something on that repo, I'm sure they'll eventually fix it. It happens from time to time on various repos.

To do the rest of the updates while excluding the Microsoft ones, try this:

```
yum clean all  
yum clean metadata  
yum makecache  
yum update --disablerepo=packages-microsoft-com-prod
```

**Note:** The first 3 lines might not be necessary in your situation, however it does give a clean start point if you haven't done updates for a while.