# Struggling to Install Puppetserver with yum on CentOS7

Tags: centos7, puppet, yum

I am trying to install puppetserver on CentOS7. I ran the following commands to first enable the puppet platform as instructed on https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.4/install_puppet.html#install_puppet :

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://yum.puppet.com/puppet7-release-el-7.noarch.rpm
yum install puppetserver -y
```

I get the following error

```
    http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet7/el/7/x86_64/puppet-agent-7.4.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=puppet7 clean metadata5 MB  00:00:13 ETA
Trying other mirror.
(9/12): net-tools-2.0-0.25.20131004git.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                      | 306 kB  00:00:03
puppetserver-7.0.3-1.el7.noarc FAILED                                                      53% [==========================================-                                     ] 7.8 MB/s |  65 MB  00:00:07 ETA
http://yum.puppetlabs.com/puppet7/el/7/x86_64/puppetserver-7.0.3-1.el7.noarch.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=puppet7 clean metadata5 MB  00:00:07 ETA
Trying other mirror.
(10/12): java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.282.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                      |  33 MB  00:00:15


Error downloading packages:
  puppet-agent-7.4.1-1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  puppetserver-7.0.3-1.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

What I have tried already:

- I installed other dependencies such as git and vim and had no problems with the installation using yum.
- I also ran `yum --enablerepo=puppet7 clean metadata5`and `yum clean all` too and tried installing puppet server straight after which failed to work also.
- Also tried running the latest version `sudo rpm -Uvh https://yum.puppet.com/puppet7-release-el-8.noarch.rpm`, changed **el7** to **el8** and same issue persisted.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: This is likely to be a temporary problem with the repo. There is something similar mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61204155/package-does-not-match-intended-download-error-when-running-yum-update

Comment: Sometimes errors like this crop up if you happen to try to retrieve packages at the same time that the repository contents and / or index is being updated.  The condition rarely lasts long.  Sometimes variations of `yum clean` help.

Comment: But ***do not*** change from `*el-7` to `*el-8`.  It is possible to install either release package, but if you must install the one that matches your actual OS (`*-el-7` for CentOS 7) in order to get other packages for that OS.  Many of those other packages do not work on the wrong OS version.

Comment: If the problem persists more than a few minutes and `yum clean all` does not resolve it then it might be time to file a ticket with Puppet.

Comment: Thank you, how would I check whether the package matches my OS? I will try the other suggestions!

Comment: @altf4 the Puppet docs you are already looking at tells you which release package to use.  For CentOS 7 it is the one whose name contains `-el-7`.  The "el" in that is for RedHat *Enterprise Linux*, of which CentOS is a clone, and the "7" is for the OS major version number.  Having installed (only) that one, the other packages you obtain via `yum` will be for the correct OS.